# Earliest and Latest ZonedDateTimes on Earth from an UTC reference time

Tags: java, timezone

I have a reference ZonedDateTime in UTC:

```
var ref = ZonedDateTime.parse("2022-01-01T14:00Z");
```

We must find the earliest and latest times on Earth based on the most extreme known TimeZones.

That would be:

- `2022-01-02T04:00+14`
- `2022-01-01T03:00-11`

What is the most reliable way to achieve this?

I'm thinking about `OffsetDateTime`, but I'm not sure it will handle daylight times correctly. Are there constants for the minimum and maximum offsets and/or TZ?

Comment: So you just want to find timezones that would have the minimum and maximum offset at that instant?

Comment: @sweeper : I will need to extract two `LocalDateTime` (at the same instant). The offsets and TZ will be discarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a stream on `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

```
var instant = Instant.parse("2022-01-01T14:00:00Z");
var minMax = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().stream()
    .mapToInt(x -> ZoneId.of(x).getRules().getOffset(instant).getTotalSeconds())
    .summaryStatistics();

var latestLocalTime = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(minMax.getMax())).toLocalDateTime();
var earliestLocalTime = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(minMax.getMin())).toLocalDateTime();
System.out.println(latestLocalTime);
System.out.println(earliestLocalTime);
```

Notice that this prints out, in Java 17:

```
2022-01-02T04:00
2022-01-01T02:00
```

The earliest time is different from what you expect. I looked into what this timezone is:

```
System.out.println(ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().stream()
    .map(ZoneId::of).min(Comparator.comparingInt(
        x -> x.getRules().getOffset(instant).getTotalSeconds()
    )));
```

It is apparently the timezone `Etc/GMT+12`. Despite its identifier, this timezone actually has an offset of -12 hours, because the `Etc/GMT` identifiers use the opposite signs. Anyway, [UTC-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9212:00) is technically observed in Baker Island and Howland Island, according to Wikipedia.

Comment: timeanddate.com seems to confirm that [Baker Island](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/usa/baker-island) and [Howland Island](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/usa/howland-island) are at UTC offset -12:00. I don’t know why they don’t seem to be in the time zone database. Possibly because both are uninhabited.

Comment: Generally I would consider the ETC/GMT+/-nn time zones technical time zones with no guarantee that they are in use anywhere on the planet. So one may consider filtering them away.